# Convert PAL to NTSC

Tags: video, dvd-burning, dvdauthor

I have some vacation DVDs which i would like to convert from PAL to NTSC.

How and/or what might be the easiest way to do this? I'm looking for a free solution.

I'm on Windows 7. I have access to ubuntu 11.10 on virtual machine if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it run properly on Windows 7 or not, last release was 2007, install in compatibility mode for XP just to be safe.

May take some experimentation:

> For those wanting to convert PAL to NTSC, download the program. Rip your movie to the hard drive with DVD decrypter. Then [open your newly ripped files with VOB blanker](http://download.videohelp.com/jsoto/vobblanker.htm). Under the title set block (center of program window), you'll see your VOB files. The center column says "video format". My example says NTSC 4:3 720x480. If you right click on the VOB's you want to convert, then select "video attributes", you'll see a new window pop up. In this window, you can change the "standard" from PAL to NTSC and vice versa. You can even change the resolution in this window.
>
> Do the above, then select or make a new output folder. Click on "process" at the bottom and let the conversion begin. You can then use DVD shrink or any other compression/burning program of your choice to burn your newly converted NTSC or PAL dvd (whichever you chose to convert to).

See first post by sadsac

http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/167922

Comment: Very promising. So far i've used VobBlanker alone. I was able to change a setting from PAL to NTSC. I'm burning the DVD now and i'll test it tomorrow morning. (+1) so far it has been a painless solution.